# Combining two variables to create new variable

Tags: r, if-statement, merge

I would like to combine two variables that have only one answer each into a single variable that has both answers.

Example

IPV_YES only has answers that are 1
IPV_NO only has answers that are 2

I would like to combine them into a single variable named IPV that would have the 1 and 2 results from both individual category.

I have tried using ifelse command but it only shows me the value of IPV_YES.

Dataset I have
[image: Dataset]

My desired outcome
[image: Desired Outcome]

Comment: `ifelse(IPV_YES == 1, 1, ifelse(IPV_NO == 2, 2, NA))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I use that it only shows the responses for IPV_YES. IPV_NO is not displayed at all in the table of results, etc.

Comment: You should provide an example dataset. @Phil's solution looks fine.

Comment: I have added images in the original post with an example dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my answer

```
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == "", NA, as.numeric(.)))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(IPV = sum(c_across(everything()), na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Rowwise:  ID
     ID   IPV
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     1
4     4     2
```

data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4, IPV_YES = c(1,"",1,""), IPV_NO = c("",2,"",2))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `coalesce` after converting the `''` to `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    transmute(ID, IPV = coalesce(na_if(IPV_YES, ""), na_if(IPV_NO, ""))) %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4, IPV_YES = c(1,"",1,""), IPV_NO = c("",2,"",2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$IPV <- ifelse(df$IPV_YES != "", df$IPV_YES, df$IPV_NO[!df$IPV_NO==""])
```

Here, we specify an `ifelse` statement; it can be glossed thus: if the value in `df$IPV_YES` is *not* blank, then give the value in `df$IPV_YES`, else give those values from `df$IPV_NO` that are not blank.

If you want to remove the `IPV_*` columns:

```
df[,2:3] <- NULL
```

Result:

```
df
  ID IPV
1  1   1
2  2   2
3  3   1
4  4   2
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4, IPV_YES = c(1,"",1,""), IPV_NO = c("",2,"",2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
replace(df, df == "", NA) %>%
  mutate(IPV = coalesce(IPV_YES, IPV_NO)) %>%
  select(ID, IPV) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
  ID IPV
1  1   1
2  2   2
3  3   1
4  4   2
```